# Why does nth-of-type not consider the class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I'm coming to terms to `nth-of-type()` ignoring class, for instance in the following:

HTML:

```
<body style="">
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="container"> things </div>
<div class="alert">alert 1</div>
<div class="alert">alert 2</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body > div.alert:nth-of-type(1) { border-color: blue; }
body > div.alert:nth-of-type(2) { border-color: green; }
body > div.alert:nth-of-type(3) { border-color: red; }
```

I would expect to have `alert 1`/`alert 2` as blue/green, however instead they are green/red.

Is there a way to achieve my goals with CSS? These alerts are created by a third-party plugin where I believe I lack simple control over both their placement in the DOM, or giving them unique CSS classes, so I'm hoping that pseudo-classes can work here without HTML modification?

My JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1jm94rye/1/

Comment: Can you explain why you would expect nth-of-type to be influenced by the class? A type is not a class.

Comment: I'm not expecting to use `nth-of-type`, I'm just trying to achieve my goal and `nth-of-type` seemed to be the best bet but obviously not